# How to extract sub-elements from a list within an XML in Python

Tags: python, json, xml, elementtree, xml.etree

I am trying to extract elements from an XML list using the Python `etree` library and to finish generating an output JSON with these elements.

The idea is to pass it a series of XPATH to extract the elements I want. I don't want to go through all the elements in the XML as there are a lot of them.

The XML looks something similar to this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Line xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Data>
        <Date>2020-01-02</Date>
        <Id>id_1</Id>
        <CodDevice>567</CodDevice>
        <DataList>
            <Item>
                <Row>1</Row>
                <Value>34.67</Value>
                <Description>WHEELS</Description>
                <Tag>tag1</Tag>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Row>2</Row>
                <Value>38.04</Value>
                <Description>MOTOR</Description>
                <Tag>tag1</Tag>
            </Item>
        </DataList>
        <MetaList>
            <Metadata>
                <Row>1</Row>
                <Value>some value</Value>
            </Metadata>
        </MetaList>
    </Data>
</Line>
```

the approach I am considering is as follows:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import json

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Line xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Data>
        <Date>2020-01-02</Date>
        <Id>id_1</Id>
        <CodDevice>567</CodDevice>
        <DataList>
            <Item>
                <Row>1</Row>
                <Value>34.67</Value>
                <Description>WHEELS</Description>
                <Tag>tag1</Tag>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Row>2</Row>
                <Value>38.04</Value>
                <Description>MOTOR</Description>
                <Tag>tag1</Tag>
            </Item>
        </DataList>
        <MetaList>
            <Metadata>
                <Row>1</Row>
                <Value>some value</Value>
            </Metadata>
        </MetaList>
    </Data>
</Line>     
"""

tag_list = [
'./Data/Date',
'./Data/Id',
'./Data/CodDevice',
'./Data/DataList/Item/Row',
'./Data/DataList/Item/Value',
'./Data/DataList/Item/Description',
'./Data/MetaList/Metadata/Row',
'./Data/MetaList/Metadata/Value'
]

elem_dict= {}
  
parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
root = ET.fromstring(data, parser=parser)

for tag in tag_list:
    for item in root.findall(tag):
        elem_dict[item.tag] = item.text
print(json.dumps(elem_dict))
```

As you can see, I try to generate a JSON which, as I pass the XPATH to the list elements, overwrites them, generating the following output:

```json
{"Date": "2020-01-02", "Id": "id_1", "CodDevice": "567", "Row": "1", "Value": "some value", "Description": "MOTOR"}
```

But what I would like to get is something similar to:

```json
{"Id":"id_1","CodDevice":"567","DataList":[{"Row":1,"Value":34.67,"Description":"WHEELS"}, {"Row":2,"Value":38.04,"Description":"MOTOR"}],"MetaList":[{"Row":1,"Value":some value}]}
```

I don't know in detail what capabilities I can use the library for, maybe there is a more efficient way to achieve this and I am overlooking it...

Any ideas on how to approach this would be great. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task involves:

- filtering of the source XML tree,
- changing names of elements and their structure (e.g. *Item* elements
  to elements of a list)
- generating a "multi-level" (nested) output.

This it why I think that the most natural approach is to write some
custom code.

Start from a function getting the text of an XML element (it will
be used further):

```
def getTxt(elem):
    return elem.text.strip()
```

Then define another function to add children to a dictionary:

```
def addChildren(dct, elem, childNames, fn=getTxt):
    for it in elem:
        tag = it.tag
        if tag in childNames:
            dct[tag] = fn(it)
```

Parameters:

- *dct* - the dictionary to add content to.
- *elem* - the source element.
- *childNames* - names of children to look for in *elem* and serve.
- *fn* - a function generating the content for each element.

To get the content for both lists, define yet another function:

```
def getItems(elem):
    lst = []
    for it in elem:
        dct = {}
        addChildren(dct, it, ['Row', 'Value', 'Description'])
        lst.append(dct)
    return lst
```

And the last step is the main code, assuming that you have your XML
tree in *root*:

```
dct = {}
nd = root.find('Data')
addChildren(dct, nd, ['Date', 'Id', 'CodDevice'])
addChildren(dct, nd, ['DataList', 'MetaList'], getItems)
```

Now *dct* contains (after some reformatting):

```
{
  'Date': '2020-01-02',
  'Id': 'id_1',
  'CodDevice': '567',
  'DataList': [
    {'Row': '1', 'Value': '34.67', 'Description': 'WHEELS'},
    {'Row': '2', 'Value': '38.04', 'Description': 'MOTOR'}
  ],
  'MetaList': [
    {'Row': '1', 'Value': 'some value'}
  ]
}
```

If you want to save it as a JSON string, run *json.dump* or *json.dumps*.

I'm not sure whether the output should contain *Date* key (your *tag_list*
contains it, but the expected output doesn't).
If it is not needed, remove *'Date'* from the first *childNames*.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [dictionary merging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/1422451) via a dict comprehension:

```py
data = root.find('.//Data')
elem_dict = {
              **{d.tag: d.text.strip() for d in data.findall('*') if d.text.strip() != ""},
              **{'DataList': [{i.tag: i.text.strip() for i in item.findall('*') if i.tag != 'Tag'} 
                               for item in data.findall('.//DataList/Item')]},
              **{'MetalList': [{m.tag: m.text.strip() for m in meta.findall('*')} 
                                for meta in data.findall('.//MetaList/Metadata')]}
             } 

print(json.dumps(elem_dict))
# {"Date": "2020-01-02", "Id": "id_1", "CodDevice": "567", 
#  "DataList": [{"Row": "1", "Value": "34.67", "Description": "WHEELS"}, 
#               {"Row": "2", "Value": "38.04", "Description": "MOTOR"}], 
#  "MetalList": [{"Row": "1", "Value": "some value"}]}
```